# React : changing css properties on hover

Tags: css, reactjs, hover

Here, I am trying to implement a change in CSS property, basically trying to move the img component with categoryImage attribute a little upwards on hover and back to original position on mouseLeave.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from '../stylesheets/style.module.css';
import { CSSTransition, TransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group';

class CategoryCard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  state = { hover: false, loadCards: false };
  toggleHover() {
    this.setState({ hover: !this.state.hover });
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    if (!this.loadCards) this.setState({ loadCards: !this.state.loadCards });
  }
  render() {
    if (this.state.hover) {
      console.log(styles.catCard.display);
    } else {
      console.log(styles.catCard);
    }
    return (
      <div className={styles.catCard}>
        <h1 className={styles.catHeading}>{this.props.categoryTitle}</h1>
        <div className={styles.imageDiv}>
          <CSSTransition
            in={this.state.loadCards}
            timeout={5000}
            classNames={{
              enter: styles['catimage-enter'],
              enterActive: styles['catimage-enter-active'],
              appear: styles['catimage-appear'],
              appearActive: styles['catimage-appear-active'],
            }}
            appear={true}
            unmountOnExit={true}
            mountOnEnter={true}
          >
            <img
              src={this.props.imageLink}
              width="40%"
              className={styles.categoryImage}
              onMouseEnter={this.toggleHover.bind(this)}
              onMouseLeave={this.toggleHover.bind(this)}
            ></img>
          </CSSTransition>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CategoryCard;
```

Here is my style.modules.css file.I want to apply a change in categoryImage attribute on mouseEnter and back to normal on mouseLeave:-

```
.catimage-appear {
  transform: scale(0.1);
}
.catimage-appear-active {
  transform: scale(0.1);
  transition: transform 2000ms cubic-bezier(0.22, 1, 0.36, 1);
}
.salesContainer {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.salesRow {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.catCard {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font: normal 10px/100% Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  width: 31%;
}

.catHeading {
  padding: 1%;
  padding-left: 5%;
  align-self: center;
}

.imageDiv {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.salesRow {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.categoryImage {
  height: 250px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS `:hover` pseudo class for this, not JS. It will be faster and less buggy.